# Cannot get http basic authentication in Mule 3 to work

Tags: mule, basic-authentication

I am having a problem with getting HTTP Basic auth. to work with Mule 3.2. We have earlier used Mule 2.1.1 without problems but now I am stuck. I have created a small test service with a configuration like this, based on examples in the Mule documentation:

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
  xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
  xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
  xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.2/mule-http.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.2/mule-vm.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.2/mule-spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
....
<spring:beans>
  <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <ss:authentication-provider>
      <ss:user-service id="userService">
        <ss:user name="ross" password="ross" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <ss:user name="anon" password="anon" authorities="ROLE_ANON"/>
      </ss:user-service>
    </ss:authentication-provider>
  </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>

<mule-ss:security-manager>
  <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider"
                                      delegate-ref="authenticationManager"/>
</mule-ss:security-manager>

<model name="testModel">
  <service name="testService">
    <inbound>
      <http:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="8888" exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
      </http:inbound-endpoint>
    </inbound>
....
```

But when directing a browser to http://localhost:8888/ I just get an exception in the mule log:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException: Registered authentication is set to com.computas.mt.mule.security.HttpBasicJBossAuthFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint http://localhost:8888. Message payload is of type: String
    at org.mule.transport.http.filters.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter.authenticateInbound(HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:160)
    at org.mule.security.AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.authenticate(AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.java:58)
    at org.mule.security.AbstractAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationFilter.java:56)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

I have checked the response headers, and all i get back from Mule is this. I would have expected to also get the headers that indicate that authentication is required:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 243
Connection: close

401 Unauthorized
```

All works fine when not using authentication. Anyone else that have experienced this and found a solution? Maybe I have done a very simple and stupid mistake, but in that case i really can't see it...
Note: We run Mule inside JBoss 4.2.1, not standalone.

Regards

Jonas Heineson

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When downgrading and using Mule 3.1.2 instead of 3.2.0 everything worked as expected. So there seem to be a bug in version 3.2.

Comment: This bug is fixed in version 3.2.1

Comment: Please provide reference to the actual BUG i.e. the JIRA link

Comment: According to the release notes for 3.2.1 it is jira key EE-2537. Can't access jira for some reason.